# Block design: derived designs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

I am now study some theorems of block design. I have a question about the derived designs.

Let $B$ be the oringinal design $t-(v,k, \lambda)$. Suppose we omit one of the points, say $P$, then we have two
sets of blocks which remain: First, $B_{1}$, consisting of the $\lambda_{1,0}$ blocks of $k$
points that did not contain $P$. Second, $B_{2}$, consisting $\lambda_{1,1}$ blocks of $k-1$
points. These are called derived designs.

The theorem says that, $B_{1}$ form a $(t-1)-(v-1,k,\lambda_{t,t-1})$ design with block intersection $\lambda^{(1)}_{i,j}=\lambda_{i+1,j}$. $B_{2}$ form a $(t-1)-(v-1,k-1,\lambda)$ design with block intersection $\lambda^{(2)}_{i,j}=\lambda_{i+1,j+1}$.

Let us consider the $B=2-(7,3,1)$ design, then we have $B_{1}=1-(6,2,1)$ with $\lambda^{(1)}_{i,j}=\lambda_{i+1,j}$. If we consider $\lambda^{(1)}_{2,0}$, I think that $\lambda^{(1)}_{2,0}=1$, but the theorem says that $\lambda^{(1)}_{2,0}=\lambda_{3,0}=0$. What is the problem about this theorem? Or could someone give me the proof of this theorem? THANKS SO MUCH.

Comment: Without some clarification it is difficult to see the meaning of the various "$\lambda$" notations being used above.  In the [block design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design#Generalization:_t-designs) $B$ with parameters $t-(v,k,\lambda)$, the usual meaning of $\lambda$ is the number of blocks each $t$-tuple appears in.  Some notation is then introduced to count the number of blocks with which a given block intersects in a certain size (possibly empty).  This deserves at least a link to the definition, and preferably an outright explanation in the body of your Question.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, the $\lambda$ here means any $t$ points are contained in exactly $\lambda$ blocks. $v$ is the total points and each block contains $k$ points. $\lambda_{i,j}$ is the block intersection number.

Comment: So what does "the block intersection number" $\lambda_{i,j}$ or $\lambda_{i,j}^{(1)}$ mean?  How does it relate to your original block design $B$?  What are the subscripts/superscripts ranging over?

Comment: The block intersection number is the number of blocks containing $P_{1}, P_{2},...P_{j}$ but do not contain $P_{j+1},...,P_{i}$. If $j=0$, $\lambda_{i,0}$ is number of blocks do not contain $P_{1},...,P_{j}$. If $i=j$, $\lambda_{j,j}$ is number of blocks containing $P_{1},...,P_{j}$. For example, $\lambda_{3,1}$ is the number of blocks containing one of the point in this block design, say $P_{1}$, but do not contain other two points, say $P_{2}, P_{3}$.